# Kafka Issue : Request joining group due to: group is already rebalancing

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, apache-kafka, microservices, kafka-consumer-api

The pod is not getting restarted,
No ongoing rebalance to finish
consumer group experiences no frequent changes,
but still rebalancing issue occurs. is there anything wrong with the configuration?

This is the Kafka configuration,

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset = earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit = true
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records = 3
spring.kafka.consumer.isolation-level = read_committed
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.interval.ms = 7200000
```

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Sure, Thanks for suggesting it. will do